# RoundDown 'argument not valid' in a public function

Tags: excel, vba

I am calling a function in which I need to round down a value, however it has a compile error: argument not valid for .RoundDown in the following code:

```
Public Function AbilityMod(ByVal x As Integer) As Integer
AbilityMod = WorksheetFunction.RoundDown((x - 10) / 2)
End Function
```

I'm new to VBA so perhaps i'm missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a second compulsory argument, `Arg2`, i.e. the number of digits to which you want to round down your number:

```
Public Function AbilityMod(ByVal x As Integer) As Integer
AbilityMod = WorksheetFunction.RoundDown((x - 10) / 2,0)
End Function
```

I guess you want it with 0, since you declare the return of your function as `Integer`.

Find more in the official [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb239505%28v=office.12%29.aspx) of the function.

However, should you use a parameter different than `0` (for example, `1`) you will anyway get a rounded number because your function is returning `As Integer`. You might test it with `13`:

```
(x-10)/2 --> 1.5
RoundDown((x-10)/2,1) --> 1.5
AbilityMod --> 2 (because AbilityMod As Integer --> 1.5 is rounded to 2).
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought if you omitted stuff it would normally default to 0 or what ever default value there is other wise stated

Comment: @Matt when you use a function in VBA, you will get a tooltip with the parameters: parameters without brackets are compulsory, parameters with square brackets are optional. For example: `myFunc(compulsoryArg, [optionalArg])`. Remember this, will avoid many errors ;)